Why is a binomial distribution bimodal if p(n+1) is an integer?
I was able to determine that the mode of a binomial distribution is the floor of $p(n+1)$ by observing the ratio between $f(x+1 | n, p)$ and $f(x | n,p)$
However, my reading states that when $p(n+1)$ is an integer, both $p(n+1)-1$ and $p(n+1)$ are modes. I can understand how this is possible, but why does this generalize to all occurrences where $p(n+1)$ is an integer?

I could write you an answer, but that answer would be exactly doing what you have described: computing the ratio between the two probabilities to see that they are equal and therefore there are both modes. If you have not done this yourself already, then what is it about doing it that confuses you?

@MishaLavrov I've simplified the ratio to $\frac{p(n-x)}{(1-p)(x+1)}$. I solve for when this ratio is greater than or equal to 1; $x \leq p(n+1) - 1$. It follows that the mode should therefore be the closest possible integer to this, $\lfloor p(n+1) \rfloor$, but I'm not sure how exactly $p(n+1) \in \mathbb{Z}$ affects this.

We can set $x$ equal to $p(n+1)-1$ or $p(n+1)$ if and only if $p(n+1) \in \mathbb Z$. (If it's not an integer, then the probability of the binomial random variable being equal to $p(n+1)-1$ is, instead, $0$.)  What happens in your calculation if $x = p(n+1)-1$?

@MishaLavrov Ahh I should've thought of that; they're equivalent because the ratio is equal to 1! Thank you very much for your time.

If $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p),$$ then for $x \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$,
$$\frac{\Pr[X = x+1]}{\Pr[X = x]} = \frac{\binom{n}{x+1} p^{x+1} (1-p)^{n-x-1}}{\binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}} = \frac{n-x}{x+1} \frac{p}{1-p}.$$
For fixed $n$, $p$, this ratio equals $1$ if
$$x = p(n+1) - 1.$$
So if $p(n+1)$ is an integer and $0 < p < 1$, then $x$ is an integer and $$\Pr[X = p(n+1) - 1] = \Pr[X = p(n+1)].$$
